# RestFB get all insight

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights, restfb

until 19 may 2013 I've use RestFB library to retrieve all insight of my facebook fan page. Now I've some problems because this method

```
Connection<Insight> insights = facebookClient.fetchConnection("PAGE_ID/insights", Insight.class);
```

gives me only 7 metrics and I can't use pagination of this object.
Anybody has same problem? How you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

this is a known bug currently at the moment:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/496912223696481?browse=search_51a3465d5abbf4197426907